# Angular 2 - don't save local session when open link in new tab

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, web-storage

I use [ng2-webstorage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-webstorage) module for save user session info. When I open link in tab after user to authorization, session data lost. How fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ng2-webstorage you can use LocalStorage or SessionStorage.

Try to use LocalStorage.